# how to fix While Magento is upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, console messages like jQuery migrate events are deprecated

Tags: magento2.4.4, adobe-commerce

how to fix While Magento is upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, console messages like jQuery migrate events are deprecated.

[image]